# Merge items in list based on condition

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a list which looks like:

```
a = ["/n abc", "def", "ghi", "/n jkl", "mno", "/n pqr", "/n stu"]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
a = ["abcdefghi", "jklmno" "pqr" "stu"]
```

Essentially, what I want the code to do is merge items in the list with the item sequentially below until it encounters an element with the substring "/n". It should do this for the entire list and then remove all instances of the substring "/n "

Comment: Try `''.join(a).replace('/n', '').split()`

Comment: is it really `/n` or is it mistake and actual you have `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = [i.strip() for i in ''.join(a).split('/n') if i]
```

However you should post your attempt first.

Comment: first element in result will be empty str - `''`

Answer (score 0):

One basic way (without using special methods):

```py
result = []
i = 0
index = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i][:2] == '\n':
        index += 1
    result[index] += a[i]
```

Please correct me if I did something wrong (it's been a long time since I used Python).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
res = []
s = ""
for i in l:
    if i.startswith("/n"):
        if s:
            res.append(s)
        s = i[3:]
    else:
        s+=i
if s:
    res.append(s)
print(res)
```